# Invalid key hash. The Key hash doesnot match. is showing if i connect through facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I have facebook integration in my app. i have to login through facebook, i have appID and system generted key hash stored in developer.facebook.com. I go through the facebook app login it is showing Invalid key hash and displaying that key hash. But if i delete the fb app from my device. and it will go to fb login through chrome and successfully taking the user details.

Now what i want to know is, why it is showing error if go through the facebook app. I want to go through the facebook app, so please give me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Paste below sample Code in Your OnCreate method of Application class ( only for getting ssh key )

```
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

MessageDigest md = null;
try {
  PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
      context.getPackageName(),
      PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
  for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
  }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
Log.i("KeyHash = ",Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Above code will print KeyHash in your Logs.
Copy and paste secret key in [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) developer panel.
**Note :** Keyhash differs according to release/debug environment or refer image below [image]